# Object not calling the good method after casting it's pointer to a base

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I have an issue where the method I'm trying to call isn't called and some other method is called instead. It is in a very weird and big design but I managed to do a example out of it. The example is still big the it's the smaller I've been able to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class IObserver 
{

};

class IAObserver : public IObserver
{
public:
    virtual void someSpecificMethod(int i) = 0;
};

class ISomeOtherObject
{
public:
    virtual void someMethodFromThatObject() = 0;
};

class SomeOtherObject : public ISomeOtherObject
{
public:
    virtual void someMethodFromThatObject()
    {
        std::cout << "Some implementation from that object" << std::endl;
    }
};

class AObserverImpl : public IAObserver, public SomeOtherObject
{
public:
    virtual void someSpecificMethod(int i)
    {
        std::cout << "Some implementation " << i << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void someMethodFromThatObject()
    {
        std::cout << "Better implementation from our object" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void addObserver(IObserver* observer) = 0;
};

class A : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void addObserver(IObserver* observer)
    {
        m_observers.push_back((IAObserver*)observer);
    }

    void notifyObservers()
    {
        std::vector<IAObserver*>::iterator it;
        for(it = m_observers.begin(); it != m_observers.end(); it++)
        {
            (*it)->someSpecificMethod(5);
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<IAObserver*> m_observers;
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new A();
    SomeOtherObject* observer = new AObserverImpl();

    a->addObserver((IObserver*)observer);
    a->notifyObservers(); //output: Better implementation from our object
}
```

Here's the Ideone http://ideone.com/yAT6M7

So as you can see, it is supposed to call the method `someSpecificMethod` but it's calling the mehod `someMethodFromThatObject`. Any clue what's going on ? Is this object slicing ? In CLion debugger, I can't even call my `someSpecificMethod` method. How can I work around this ?

Comment: `(IObserver*)observer` does not do what you think it does - and you are invoking UB

Comment: @UnholySheep Good to know thank you, can you explain why and what to do instead ?

Comment: You need to use the proper C++ casts, e.g.: `dynamic_cast` - I fixed your example here: http://ideone.com/i3zUsC

Comment: @UnholySheep Thank you, will look at it and learn about dynamic_cast

Comment: @Winter -- Remove the cast.  What error does the compiler give you?  If it gave you an error, read it carefully.  By using a `C`-style cast such as `(IAOberver *)`, you told the compiler "I'm not listening to you, so shut up".  Never cast away error messages, unless you are fully aware of what the error is telling you, know the consequences, and know full well what you're doing.

Comment: Also, 1) why in `main` are you using `new`?  C++ is not C#.   `A a;` is all you need, and 2) Your base class is missing a virtual destructor.  If you went in and tried to `delete` that object you added to the vector, you would invoke undefined behavior if you attempt to delete it through a base class pointer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, because my main was trying to reproduce the real context. This example is a reconstruction. I was just trying to make the smallest example for it. Also, why are you so upset at people for learning ?

Comment: Where am I being "upset"?  Read compiler errors, don't mask them.  Add virtual destructor, don't use `new` unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the core of your problem is a cross-cast. You have an inheritance hierarchy that looks like this:

```
[SomeOtherObject]     [IAObserver]
              \         /
               \       /
            [AObserverImpl]
```

Inside `main()`, `observer` has dynamic type `AObserverImpl*`, but static type `SomeOtherObject*`. Then you try to retrieve the `IAObserver` part of the object which also contains this `SomeOtherObject`. This is called a cross-cast, a cast across the inheritance tree of an object.

But by the time you do the cast, the information that `*observer` is actually part of an `AObserverImpl` has been lost from the type system. So the C-style cast, which is strictly static, degrades into a `reinterpret_cast` (!!). You get an `IAObserver*` that actually still points to the very same `SomeOtherObject`, and trying to then use it only leads to nasty bugs at best.

This is the kind of reasons why you should never use a C-style cast on pointers unless you have a good reason and you know it. Had you used a `static_cast`, it would have failed to compile.

To solve this, you need to somehow get back the lost type information to perform your cast. Two parties still have that information:

**The developer**:

```
// Downcast to AObserverImpl, then upcast along the other branch
// The upcast is superfluous, but written here for clarity
a->addObserver(
    static_cast<IAObserver*>(
        static_cast<AObserverImpl*>(observer)
    )
);
```

And... **dynamic_cast**:

```
// dynamic_cast uses RTTI to walk the inheritance graph at runtime.
// It will also do error checking :)
a->addObserver(dynamic_cast<IAObserver*>(observer));
```

Comment: Basically the problem is that programmers believe they've outsmarted the compiler by C-style casting away the errors they receive.  Then stuff like this bites them in the end.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie either that, or they don't know any better because they have been taught that casts in C++ are "just like C, with the parentheses". But that's a rant for another day ;)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are using C-style casts, when you should be using a [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) instead.

C-style casts know nothing of C++ objects, and therefore they do no type checking. In order to cast between base classes in a multiple-inheritance situation, you must use a `dynamic_cast` to make sure that everything is set up correctly for the new pointer.

If you replace all of the C-style casts in your sample to `dynamic_cast`, then it should work.

If you want to read more about this, search for C++, v-tables, and multiple inheritance.

Comment: C-style casts do know about C++ objects, and they can perform `static_cast`s, pointer adjustments included. Only when you mess up do they degrade into a blunt `reinterpret_cast`.