# shared_ptr with multiple interfaces

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Consider the following classes:

```
class MyInterface1 {
    ...
};
class MyInterface2 {
    ...
};
class MyClass : public MyInterface1, public MyInterface2 {
    ...
};
```

If I have the following code:

```
void MyFunction(shared_ptr<MyInterface1>& out); // returns a make_shared<MyClass>

shared_ptr<MyInterface1> c1;
shared_ptr<MyInterface2> c2;
MyFunction(c1);
c2 = c1;
```

I'm unable to assign c2 to c1.

Additionally, it also won't compile if I just call `MyFunction(c2)`, which I would expect to work since MyClass is derived from both MyInterface1 and MyInterface2. This seems like a compiler bug (Visual Studio 2015 Update 3) that might be worth sharing. Can anyone reproduce this?

Comment: No, this is not a compiler bug.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `shared_ptr`, this doesn't work with raw pointers either.

Comment: `MyClass` can be a `MyInterface1` or a `MyInterface2`, but there is no relationship between `MyInterface1` and `MyInterface2.

Comment: Just because you happen to have a `MyClass` that combines `MyInterface1` and `MyInterface2` doesn't mean that all possible derivations of `MyInterface1` are similarly related. Why should the compiler make such an assumption?

Answer (score 4):

`MyInterface1` and `MyInterface2` are totally unrelated types.  Just because the object pointed to by `c1` has a runtime type that inherits from both, the static types are incompatible and you will have to use a cast to assign one to the other

```
shared_ptr<MyInterface1> c1;
shared_ptr<MyInterface2> c2;
MyFunction(c1);
c2 = dynamic_pointer_cast<MyInterface2>(c1);
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d13a69d4e44cd78c)

This will, of course, only work if the actual dynamic type of `*c1` inherits from `MyInterface2`.  Like any `dynamic_cast`, [`dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) will return `nullptr` if the types are incompatible.

Answer (score -5):

You can do this with raw pointers but it's not possible to do with a shared_ptr. Don't use shared_ptr, but instead do this:

```
void MyFunction(MyInterface1* out); // returns a new MyClass()

MyInterface1* c1;
MyInterface2* c2;
MyFunction(c1);
c2 = (MyInterface2*)c1;
MyFunction((MyInterface1*)c2);
```

It's certainly a lot cleaner, easier and more maintainable. Also its faster since you're not using shared_ptr anymore and has less overhead. Don't use shared_ptr if you care about performance.

Comment: Not the best choice for multiple reasons. Avoid C-style casting - it can hurt you bad. Returning a new object through an argument with a pointer with no explicit ownership is in most cases another bad idea .

Comment: Really bad advice, dude. C-style cast is like God saying, "Trust me. I know what I'm doing." Better hope that God is right because it's going to happen right or wrong. In this case you're playing God and you're wrong.

Comment: I'm the only person who actually offered a solution and everybody else is saying its a bad idea. If its a bad idea take it up with the creator of the language. This wasn't a question about style so take your "holy war" elsewhere... The developer asked a question and I was the only person to actually give an answer while everyone else just made comments complaining and no valuable insight... No wonder people have an issue with the community.

Comment: How is it undefined? Its derived from those two base classes.

Comment: after `c2 = (MyInterface2*)c1;` the address `c2` refers to will not necessarily be the same as that of c1. No I'm wrong here. there is no relationship that would make that happen here. My apologies. It just violates strict aliasing.

Comment: You're saying it violates strict aliasing only because MyInterface1 doesn't derive from MyInterface2 (or vice-versa). If it did, this would be fine, correct?

Comment: Sort-of yes. The address could change in that case.

Comment: The creator of the language started from C. Learn C++. Learn C++ history. Stop giving inane advice.

Comment: Much arguing but no explanation... See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41598341/3233393) to know why that cast will only fling you to UB-land.